# Mapping logical queries to elasticsearch query DSL

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I am fairly new to Elasticsearch. I am trying to map basic logical queries to elasticsearch query DSL.

I understand that bool is used to make boolean(logical) queries to ES. I can map queries like if (cond1 && cond2), but I cannot understand how to make OR queries like if(cond1 || cond2)

Logical Query

```
if(attr1==val1 && attr2=val2){}
```

Elastic Search DSL

```
"bool" : {
    "must" : {
        ["term":{"attr1":"val1"}, {"term":"attr2":"val2"}]
    }
}
```

What do I write for `if(attr1==val1 || attr2==val2)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this by using the `|` (or) operator ([see docs](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html#query-combination)):

```
s = search.Search()
s = s.filter(Q('term', attr1='val1') | Q('term', attr2='val2'))
```

This is equivalent to

```
"bool" : {
    "should" : {
        ["term":{"attr1":"val1"}, {"term":"attr2":"val2"}]
    },
    "minimum_should_match": 1
}
```

Comment: I am not using python. Can you provide me  a corresponding JSON query DSL for the same?

Comment: Thanks, I also got the idea from here - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/combining-filters.html Should have gone through this first!